# Where provide "morphMap" setting for standalone eloquent usage without laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using eloquent as standalone module with slim framework (https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/database-eloquent.html)

My question is - where i can provide polymorphic relations "morphMap" setting?

Comment: I'm using Slim 4 with Slim Skeleton and having morphMap in index.php works for me. I guess you could also define a BaseModel and have all the other models inherit from it.

Answer (score 3):

you should define the `morphMap` in each function that define in `morph` or `morphToMany`:

> example::

here is the `comments` function model:

```
class comment extends Model
{

    public function commentable(){

        Relation::morphMap([
            'posts' => 'App\post',
            'videos' => 'App\video',
        ]);

        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

here is the `post` function model:

```
class post extends Model
{
    public function comments(){

        Relation::morphMap([
            'posts' => 'App\post',
        ]);
        return $this->morphMany('App\comment','commentable');
    }
}
```

> dont forget to add this namespace:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but in laravel  You may register the morphMap in the boot function of your AppServiceProvider or create a separate service provider if you wish. So the question - is I can do same thing  without laravel?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. This is a valid response that answers the question as asked.

Comment: Relation::morphMap() sets the global morph map - not just in the context of where you call it

Answer (score 1):

To avoid to use morphMap in each model's relation you can override boot method setting there your morphMap:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected static function boot(){`
        parent::boot();

        Relation::morphMap([
            'posts' => 'App\post',
        ]);
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', commentable);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will affect every model, almost like you place it in AppServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

Today i searched for the same problem.

Slim4 & Eloquent.

I have to following code in my container boot file and it works.

`container.php`

```
// eloquent
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($dbSettings);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();


$container->set('db', function ($container) use ($capsule) {
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap([
        App\Models\Order::class
    ]);
    return $capsule;
});
```

now my database contains `order`  instead of `App\Models\Order`

Don`t know if this is the correct way.

But this way I only have to write it in one place.